# Is there any worldwide on demand photo printing API?

Tags: api, printing, photo

I run a website where users can upload art images and photographs. Now, I am looking for a photo printing API to sell printed products to visitors. I want to do this entirely from my own app, under my own domain. Basically, I need something similar to Google Cloud Print, but I really need high quality print products, like large canvases and aluminium prints. This print service would preferably be globally available and at least take care of the actual printing, international shipping and - if I would be really lucky - also customer service.

So far, I have not been very successful, because most print facilities do not have a very user-friendly API and/or require a minimum number of orders that is completely ridiculous. Suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Peecho](http://www.peecho.com). The [Peecho Simple Print API](http://www.peecho.com/simple-print-api) allows developers to build professional printing functionality entirely in their own apps, with a very simple REST API to place print orders through Peecho's cloud print network. It is prepaid, so you can build all screens yourself, including checkout and payment (so you can decide on your own pricing and profit). There is no minimum order volume - you can start with 1 piece.

If your website has photos in a gallery, it may be faster to just implement the javascript-based [Simple Print Button](http://www.peecho.com/simple-print-button). The Simple Print Button allows digital publishers to sell their content in print, by adding a single line of code to their website. It includes checkout and payment, so there will be less effort for you.

For both services, Peecho offers a dashboard for order management and tracking, worldwide production in print facilities like CEWE COLOR and RPI Print, international shipping and delivery and even customer service. Products range from hardcover books to premium quality wall decoration like aluminium prints, as offered by for example Rijksmuseum Amsterdam.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at https://www.kite.ly for mobile print SDK's and RESTful print API offerings.

[image]

Full disclosure: I'm cofounder of the company so a little biased, but our products and offerings also happen to be really really good (especially from a developer integration point of view) so I'll take any chance to shout about it ;)

We're all about high quality, beautiful personalised products and we're adding new ones all the time: Photo Prints, Magnets, Postcards, Posters, Stickers, Phone cases, etc, etc...

- REST Print API: https://www.kite.ly/docs/1.1/
- iOS Print SDK: https://github.com/OceanLabs/iOS-Print-SDK
- Android Print SDK: https://github.com/OceanLabs/Android-Print-SDK

Several of our partners also have millions of users hitting our services so you'll be in good company!

Here's a peek at our iOS Print SDK (Android is similar, and REST API is naturally without UI and for more advanced use cases):

[image: iOS SDK Overview]

Comment: It looks like SDK won't be supported anymore since Kite.Ly was taken by Prodigi. Shame. Is there any similar alternative to Kite.Ly (via full SDK, not just REST API)?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the Printchomp Print API http://printchomp.com/api . The now have over 10,000 printers across North America including photo printing on demand. The Printchomp Print API is truly restful and has adopted Hypertext Application Language (HAL) to make consumable and explorable. All API calls and responses are very consistent making it easy to program with.

Comment: The site does not seem to work anymore today.

Answer (score 1):

There is also http://print.milkbooks.com/  They are a single image print API that is plugs easily into any platform. Margins are high as is price point but that is offset by the super high quality of the product. You have control of the RRP so you can reduce price at any time. Once the user has ordered a book you no longer have any involvement in the process as they handle everything, from payment to a full refund even if damaged during transit.

With an extensive product range from single art prints to notecards, canvases to gallery frames and photo books including a range of Moleskine options the variety is surprisingly varied considering they are reputed to be a specialist artistic book publisher.

The API is simple to integrate, requires no investment on your part, is multi platform, handles all aspects of the order process. The API is scalable as it is handled by Amazon Web Services so grows with your company. It's customizable as you can develop your own range of products however this does require some investment on your part and because they have adopted a https always on policy, security is pretty tight too.

Answer (score 0):

There is also http://www.theprintersinc.co.uk/ They have a RESTful API as well, no sign-up fees, worldwide delivery and no minimum orders. In fact your app can still make orders even if your account balance has got to zero. Your orders would be placed on hold until you top up your account. They print on 12 Giclee fine art printers and can print from A5 prints to a whopping 60" x 40" canvas...  They also have free UK delivery as well.

Comment: That one apparently didn't make it... website no longer exists.